# How to fix No route error when using SurfaceController in Umbraco 7.1.8?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to figure out how to get a simple Contact Form SurfaceController working. The problem is that when I try to navigate to the Contact Us page, I get a "No route in the route table matches the supplied values." error.

My surface controller:

```
namespace UmbracoSurface2.Controllers
{
    public class ContactFormSurfaceController : SurfaceController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return PartialView("ContactForm", new ContactFormViewModel());
        }
    }
}
```

My ContactForm partial:

```
@model UmbracoSurface2.Models.ContactFormViewModel

<form>
    <div class="controls controls-row">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { rows="5" })
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <button id="contact-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary input-medium pull-right">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and my template:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}
@Html.Action("Index", "ContactFormController")
```

The one big difference between mine and the screencasts and examples I've found is that I'm using Visual Studio 2013 so the ASP.NET Website template has a newer version of MVC which I had to remove to get the UmbracoCms NuGet package to install. I also tried it without adding MVC to the project at the beginning.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated,

Jason

Comment: SurfaceControllers are ONLY for user interacting. So for example a post from a form. You have to use RenderMvcController. http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/custom-controllers

Comment: I'm not sure how what I did isn't user interaction, especially since it's the exact example used by the Umbraco team. Anyway, I've posted the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, as per Dan's answer [here](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/57674-No-route-error-when-using-SurfaceController-in-Umbraco-718?p=0#comment196854) on the Umbraco forum, the problem was a dumb mistake on my part. The @Html.Action line in the template should be:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "ContactFormSurface")
```

Jason